# how to code something like (cell+1).value in openpyxl

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

I have an excel like:

```
-blank-                    
aaaa            
1         
2         
3          
-blank-  
bbbb   
1   
2   
3
```

I am trying to do:

1) check if cell has a value or not

2) if it doesn't have a value then write second cells value(ex. aaaa) (until the next blank cell comes up) to the B column but I think I am so far away from the result

so the result will be something like:

```
column A    column B   
-blank-     aaaa  
 aaaa       aaaa   
1           aaaa   
2           aaaa   
3           aaaa  
-blank-     bbbb  
bbbb        bbbb  
1           bbbb  
2           bbbb   
3           bbbb
```

The code:

```
import openpyxl

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('deneme.xlsx')
sheet=wb.active
cell_range1 = sheet['A1':'A8']
a=sheet['A']
b=sheet['B']

for row in cell_range1:
    for cell in row:
        value = cell.value
        if value is None:
            for i in range(???):
                new_value=sheet.cell( row=(i+1), column=1 ).value
                print( new_value )
            for index in range( 1, ??? ):
                for cell in b:
                    b[index].value=new_value
                    print (b[i])
        else:
            print ("I dont know what to do")
wb.save( 'sonuc1.xlsx' )
```

Comment: Look at `cell.offset()`

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks